# What's the difference between Oracle Encryption and SSL

Tags: oracle, authentication, ssl

Is the Oracle Encryption good enough to encrypt Network trafic?

Or should I use the SSL option?

Update:
- Network = LAN
- With the Oracle Net manager, you can enable Encryption (AES256 for instance) or you can set up SSL.

Is the Encryption enough? When sniffing with Wireshark the data is indeed encrypted but the Protocol stays TNS. With SSL you get TLSv1.2.

I'm also looking for the option with the leaset performance drop.

Comment: When you say "Oracle Encryption" what part of the Oracle product landscape do you have in mind? Also, what sort of network traffic are you considering? DB Link? LAN/WAN? Internet?

Comment: LAN network traffic. I'm referring to the Encryption Tab in the Oracle Net Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the general configuration setup of TLS/SSL, you will have to get a certificate issued for the database. Once you have the certificate, you need to put it into a wallet, and then configure your listener to use the wallet. Also, for all the client who wants to connect to the database you will have to give them the trusted certificate and client setup will have to configured to use the certificate for validation.

For native network encryption, you need use a flag in sqlnet.ora to indicate whether you `require/accept/reject` encrypted connection. In case of server sqlnet.ora, the flag is `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER`, and for client it's `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT`. Default value of the flag is `accepted`. This means you can get away without having to configure all client to use encryption for the connection. All you need is to configure the server to use network encryption.

The advantage of native network encryption over TLS/SSL is that you hardly need to do any configuration on the client. However the down side of this method is that you will not be knowing if you are connected to the intended database(server). To a certain extent, man-in-the-middle attack is possible with native network encryption. If an attacker can get into the network and redirect clients to use a malicious database, clients will not be knowing about this although all the communications will be encrypted. However, if the attacker joins the network after the client has finished connecting with the real database, he can't do any damage.

So, it all boils down to where you want to compromise. If you believe the risk of someone impersonating the database in your network is low, you should go ahead with native network encryption. However, if you want maximum security, use TLS/SSL. The downside of TLS/SSL is that it's harder to setup and maintain. You will have to reconfigure all the client connecting to the database, and everytime the server certificate changes you will have to again go to the client for reconfiguration.

Here's a great video explaining both, and the answer is mostly copied from this.
[Russ Lowenthal, Director of Product Management for Oracle Security Products explains database security](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NFpvXXbR_w).

Regarding performance comparison between the two method, I don't have anything available at this moment.I will update this answer once I find something. You can see [this](https://www.doag.org/formes/pubfiles/8635200/Oracle-Datenbank-12c---SQLNET-encryption.pdf) for a comparison between unencrypted database vs native network encryped database performance.

Hope this will be helpful in some way. Thanks

Comment: Man, what an answer. Thx.

Comment: "If you believe the risk of someone impersonating the database in your network is low". Finding a scenario where an attacker is in position to sniff on your traffic but not in position to ARP/DNS poison the clients or otherwise redirect traffic to a machine he controls is pretty rare to say the least. Oracle Native Network Encryption is not suitable for any purpose.